# CM Server Phantom.js recommendation to move dataFolder does not work - has anyone implemented this?

Tags: security, content-management, server-role

I would like to know if the Sitecore Content Management Server security recommendation for phantom.js actually works? Has anyone successfully implemented it?
I am specifically talking about the recommendation that the dataFolder be changed from  "/App_Data" to "/data". I don't understand the benefit of this and surely all sorts of things would beak if you just did that. I totally get removing phantom.js from CD servers, I also get the recommendations to restrict Sitecore account access but I don't understand moving the dataFolder and I don't think moving it in the way described in the Sitecore documentation will work.

Following is an extract from the Sitecore documentation that I am trying to follow. https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/limit-access-to-phantomjs.html
"
Place PhantomJS outside the webroot folder
PhantomJS is located in the \$(dataFolder)\tools\phantomjs\ folder. The $(dataFolder) variable defaults to App_Data, which places PhantomJS in the \App_Data\tools\phantomjs\ folder. This can potentially give outsiders access to the phantomjs.exe program file if Sitecore security settings are not configured properly.

Sitecore references PhantomJS through the ContentTesting.PhantomJS.ExecutablePath setting in the \App_Config\Sitecore\ContentTesting\Sitecore.ContentTesting.config patch file.

To move the PhantomJS folder:

Navigate to the \App_Config\Include\ folder.

Create a patch file named, for example, MovePhantomJSFolder.config.

Insert the following configuration:

```
<sitecore
  xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" 
  xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/" 
  xmlns:security="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/security/">  
    <sc.variable name="dataFolder" value="/data" />
</sitecore>
```

Save the patch file.
"

Comment: Have you actually _tried_ doing anything at all here?  If so, what were the error messages?

Comment: I got a "Required license is missing: Runtime" - this is obvious given that license.xml sits in App_data and Sitecore is probably looking for it under /data. If I move license.xml to /data then Sitecore seems to work (i did not thoroughly test) ... but I still don't see the point of moving the folder from /App_Data to /data.

Answer (score 0):

Having read that I think it's a bit of a strange wording. I believe you have two options here.

1. Follow the article you linked to and move the entire datafolder to /data instead.
2. If you only want to patch the location of PhantomJS, you can create a slightly different patch, to change the setting of ContentTesting.PhantomJS.ExecutablePath instead:

   ```
   <configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
     <sitecore>
       <settings>
         <setting name="ContentTesting.PhantomJS.ExecutablePath" value="your/path/to/phantomjs.exe" />
       </settings>
     </sitecore>
   </configuration>
   ```

This patch file should then be put in your App_Config/Include folder.

Please note with either option you need to keep the datafolder inside the webroot.

Comment: Thanks Trayek, I have tried various combinations of this and I have to conclude that there is a bug in Sitecore 9.0 that actually does not take this setting into consideration. I copied the phantomjs folder to a new location leaving the old folder intact minus the exe file. I changed the setting and checked showconfig and double checked the path on the command prompt. PhantomJS would not work until I copied the exe back to the original location even though I deleted it from the new location that the setting was pointing too!

Comment: I got a note from Sitecore support - they are going to update the documentation.